# Get data from two tables depending on data from one in a single query

Tags: sql

I'm making a simple forum, and in the listing of the threads i want the classical "last post by (user) at (date)" to show. I'm using only one table to contain all the posts in the forum, where posts with the parentPost-field not equal to null are replies to a thread.

These are the tables and necessary fields i need data from:

forumPosts

- **id**: integer, primary key
- **title**: string value
- **date**: string value
- **parentPost**: integer (This field = ID of the initial post in the thread. If it's NULL, the post is an "initial thread post")
- **author**: integer, foreign key to the users table
- **countAnswers**: integer
- **lastPost**: integer, (This field = the ID of the last post which was replied to it. Only used when the parentPost-field = NULL)

users

- **userid**: integer, primary key
- **firstName**: string value
- **lastName**: string value

As of now, i have this query:

```
SELECT forumPosts.id, forumPosts.title, forumPosts.date, forumPosts.author, forumPosts.countAnswers, users.firstName, users.lastName 
FROM forumPosts 
INNER JOIN users ON forumPosts.author = users.userid 
WHERE forumPosts.parentPost IS NULL ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Returns all I need (ID, Title, Date, Author and how many replies it has), except for the date and author of the last posted reply.

In addition, I'd like to fetch the following:

The date from the last post in the thread, that is the post with the highest ID *and* parentPost = forumPosts.id. I'd also want to fetch the firstName and lastName from the user that posted this reply.

I've been fooling around now for a long time with different joins and derived tables and such, but I can't seem to get this right. Ideally, i'd want a table returned with the following fields:

- id
- title
- date
- firstName
- lastName
- countAnswers
- lastReplyDate
- lastReplyFirstName
- lastReplyLastName

To me, it seems possible, but I obviously can't make it.

I hope you understood my somewhat complex question, and i thank you a lot for all answers.

#### The sollution

```
SELECT        forumPosts.id, forumPosts.title, forumPosts.date, forumPosts.author, forumPosts.countAnswers, users.firstName, users.lastName, 
                     lastPost.date AS lastPostDate, lastUser.firstName AS lastPostFirstName, lastUser.lastName AS lastPostLastName
FROM            forumPosts AS lastPost INNER JOIN
                     users AS lastUser ON lastPost.author = lastUser.userid INNER JOIN
                     forumPosts INNER JOIN
                     users ON forumPosts.author = users.userid ON lastPost.id = forumPosts.lastPost
WHERE        (forumPosts.parentPost IS NULL)
ORDER BY forumPosts.id DESC
```

That worked. So typical, finding my own answer a minute after i've spent a lot of time writing a post here :-\

Answer (score 2):

If "thread" is an important concept to your system--and it appears that's the case--I would model it as a separate entity. Identifying threads by posts that have no parent is going to cause you grief as you're just beginning to discover.

For one thing to find all the threads:

```
SELECT ... FROM posts WHERE parent IS NULL
```

depending on database vendor isn't typically performant because NULL values usually aren't indexed.

Create a Thread table and all these problems go away.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f.id, f.title, f.date, 
 u1.firstName, u1.lastName, f.countAnswers,
 r1.date AS lastReplyDate,
 u2.firstName AS lastReplyFirstName
 u2.lastName AS lastReplyLastName
FROM forumPosts f
 INNER JOIN users u1 ON (f.author = u1.userid)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (forumPosts r1 INNER JOIN users u2 ON r1.author = u2.userid)
  ON (f.id = r1.parentPost)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN forumPosts r2 
  ON (f.id = r1.parentPost AND r1.id < r2.id)
WHERE f.parentPost IS NULL 
 AND r2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY f.id DESC;
```